# Is it possible to create extension methods for classes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I wonder if it is possible to create extension methods for classes (not interfaces) in TypeScript?

The class I want to extend is from external npm package and is declared as:

```
export declare class MyComponent
```

On Stack Overflow I've found only examples with strings and dates which are declared as interfaces.

Comment: You can add some functionality to prototype

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, typescript supports the inheritance concept fully.

Just type `export` before the class declaration.

And you can import the class easily.

Comment: Extensions != inheritance.

Comment: Yes, I want to add extension methods to the existing class, not inherit it.

Comment: ohk then i am sorry , i just misunderstood the question

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how the class was exported? Not sure if babel, typescript (and whatever other languages) all create the same ES5 conversion for classes. At least the super calls might be handled differently, possibly causing problems.

Now, if the used library creates ES6 classes, then that might work. Otherwise, I'd be careful with such a statement.